# Default value of check_box in rails, work with failing validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set the default value of a check box on a form so that it will be true UNLESS a user unchecked it. Normally, I could just set the :checked attribute to true on the checkbox

`f.check_box :send_emails, :checked => true`

However, if validations on the form fail, and the user unchecked the box, it will again be checked when the "new" action is re-rendered. Even though the value on the user object is indeed false when the re-rendering happens, because I have that "checked" attribute to true, it ignores that value.

To get around this, I put this in the controller for hte new action

`@user.send_emails ||= true`

It seems ugly, so I'm looking for a difference approach. Anyone come up with something different?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the default value of `:send_emails` to `true` in the migration.

Here is an example, creating a migration to change the default value of a field:

```
class AddDefaultTrueToSendEmails < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_default(:users, :send_emails, true)
  end
end
```